# IOS app dont work with Individual license with smartface 4.5

Tags: smartface.io

I have create test application and get export for ios with "Smartface Demo" License and it works with Xcode but if i export the test app with individual license the app dont work on xcode with and error "[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.".
Do i make some mistake or something wrong with license?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was during installation of Smartface 4.5 installed version of Node.js was not support latest version and i reinstall Node.js with following link
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.4.1/ and problem solved!